# Android Resource Linking Failed - Error: Failed Processing Manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

<application

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**I have a code at Android Studio and it gives an error:**

> Android resource linking failed
> c:\x\x\x\x\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:37:
> error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.xx.xx:mipmap/ic_launcher)
> not found.
> c:\x\x\x\x\app\build\intermediates\bundle_manifest\release\AndroidManifest.xml:37:
> error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher_round (aka
> com.xx.xx:mipmap/ic_launcher_round) not found. error: failed
> processing manifest.

I've invalidated caches, cleaned project, rebuilt project, renew image assets but still it gives error.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried checking that `ic_launcher` exists in your `mipmap` folder, and that this folder is part of the `release` configuration?

Comment: when i check, i can see my icons (ic_launcher and ic_launcher_round) in main/androidmanifest but doesn't show at release/androidmanifest. also i have 6 different mipmap folders (mipmap any-dpi26, mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi etc.). Does path name difference affect that?

Comment: If it isn't in your release directory, then it might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sir you added images on assets you can put image on mipmap folder and then run rebuild again.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4gV0.png)Check when creating the asset image to select "main" and not "debug" before clicking on "finish"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).